# How spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server uses client_secret_jwt?

Tags: spring-security

OAuth 2.1 how to use client_secret_jwt ?

spring-boot：2.7.0
spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server：0.3.0

Project address: https://github.com/xuxiaowei-com-cn/oauth2.1.git